# How can I insert social media URLs in following code

Tags: php, wordpress, url, jscript

I have following code in my WordPress site (footer). This part is about the Social Media Icons. here how and where I can insert URLs to each Social Media icons ?

[ct_icon icon="%5B%7B%22icon%22%3A%22fa%20fa-facebook%22%2C%22icon_link%22%3A%22%23%22%7D%2C%7B%22icon%22%3A%22fa%20fa-twitter%22%2C%22icon_link%22%3A%22%23%22%7D%2C%7B%22icon%22%3A%22fa%20fa-behance%22%2C%22icon_link%22%3A%22%23%22%7D%2C%7B%22icon%22%3A%22fa%20fa-youtube-play%22%2C%22icon_link%22%3A%22%23%22%7D%2C%7B%22icon%22%3A%22fa%20fa-linkedin%22%2C%22icon_link%22%3A%22%23%22%7D%5D" align="center" el_class="style-footer2"]

Browser display of this part is attached[image]

I need to insert Social Media URLs to particular code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The part that is assigned to the `icon` parameter is url encoded. When you decode it it looks like this:

```
[{"icon":"fa fa-facebook","icon_link":"#"},{"icon":"fa fa-twitter","icon_link":"#"},{"icon":"fa fa-behance","icon_link":"#"},{"icon":"fa fa-youtube-play","icon_link":"#"},{"icon":"fa fa-linkedin","icon_link":"#"}]
```

Assuming there is no better way, modify that and url encode it again and assign it to the `icon` parameter again and you should see updated icons.

Comment: Thing is I can't find anywhere that (section, widget, plugin) to update this URLs, I only have footer section and there are several footers to choose. Also there are footer edit option when I going to Edit option I only see this code section